# Javascript delete leaving undefined(null) value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to delete an element returned from my API call however the element i delete is leaving an "undefined" to be displayed.

```
var nutrientsLink = "http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/list?format=json&lt=n&sort=n&api_key=JXUX86YZ9mBl4jwofXb3GcwQcYehmUxQ23JwjK1q&offset=58&max=1000";

//Calls URL for nutrientList
$http.get(nutrientsLink).success(function (data) {
     //Stores the successful input
     delete data.list.item[0];
     data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: You have to slice it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: you can use `data.list.item.splice(0,1)`

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is [array.shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

```
data.list.shift()
```

Answer (score 0):

use **data.list.item.splice(0,1)** instead of **delete data.list.item[0]**.